# android: changing date format

Tags: android, parsing, datetime

i want to display date in "dd MMM yyyy" format. My input date is sometime 
30 Dec 2015 19:57:15 and some cases it is Dec 30, 2015 11:59:20 AM

I have the code which gives error for the second case.
How can i do it in such way it handles date in either form or any other new format

```
 DateFormat toFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd MMM yyyy");
    toFormat.setLenient(false);
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = toFormat.parse(dateSent);
        date = toFormat.parse("Dec 30, 2015 11:59:20 AM");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: if(dateSent.indexOf(" ") >=3){ Dec 30} else{30 Dec }

Answer (score 1):

You can do like:

```
   /**
     * Convert Date from-to Format
     *
     * @param date
     * @return
     */
    public static String convertDate(String date, String fromFormat, String toFormat) {
        try {
            return new SimpleDateFormat(toFormat, Locale.ENGLISH).format(new SimpleDateFormat(fromFormat, Locale.ENGLISH).parse(date));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Date Converting " + date + " : " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat toFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd MMM yyyy");
DateFormat toFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat( "MMM dd yyyy");
toFormat.setLenient(false);
Date date = null;
try {
    date = toFormat.parse(dateSent);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if(date == null){
    try {
        date = toFormat1.parse(dateSent);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
return date;
```